# Need help on modification to mySQL MATCH AGAINST query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple jQuery/PHP autocomplete text box that gets the matches from mySQL. In my case if a *name* in the DB is

```
Brand new iPhone and iPod case
```

and the $q is

```
iph
```

the textbox will not pop out the above product name for me to select it until I write the entire matching word.

With wildcards I get my expected result, but when $q is

```
iphone ipod
```

I will not get the above product name.

```
$q = $_GET["q"];
WHERE name LIKE '%$q%'
```

What I have now is this below and my question is if there is a way to have the result before write the full word AND also to support the iphone ipod issue.

```
$q = $_GET["q"];
$words = explode(" ", $q);
$all = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(" +",$words));
WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+" . $all . "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$all = mysql_real_escape_string(implode("* +",$words));


WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('+" . $all . "*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: BTW: you might want to do a `$words = array_filter($words);` to prevent empty matches when people are using multiple spaces.